# How can I generate lists of size k elements if I am given a bunch of combinations, each combination having k-1 elements?

Tags: java, recursion, combinations, hashset

In a way, it is the reverse of the problem of generating subsets of size k from an array containing k+1 elements.

For example, if somebody gives me the pairs {a,b} , {a,c} , {b,c} , {a,e} , {b,e}, {a,f}, I need an algorithm that will tell me the triplets {a,b,c} and (a,b,e} are completely covered for their pairwise combinations in the pairs given to me.  I need to generalize from pair/triplet in my example to the case k/k+1

My hunch was that there would be a well documented and efficient algorithm that solves my problem.  Sadly, searching the internet did not help obtaining it. Questions already posted in stackoverflow do not cover this problem.  I am thereby compelled to post this question to find my solution.

Comment: Do you want to generate a list of _every_ set that is "covered"? e.g., if {c, e} was added, would you also report {a, c, e}, {b, c, e}? Can you give an example input/output for k=3 in addition to your current k=2 example?

Comment: I don't know of any standard or well known algorithm for this, but I'm currently working on one that I can post tomorrow (gotta go to bed right now).

Comment: Yes, Curtis.  I want every set that is covered.  For the k/k+1 case of 3/4 - if I am given {a,b,c}, {a,b,d}, {a,c,d}, {b,c,d}, {b,c,e}, my algorithm must identify {a,b,c,d}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with an established algorithm for this and you didn't ask for a specific language so I've written up a C# algorithm that accomplishes what you've asked and matches the test values provided. It doesn't have much real-world error checking. I've got a .Net fiddle you can run to see the results within a web browser. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ErwTeg

It works by converting your array of arrays (or similar container) to a dictionary with every unique value as a key and the value for each key being every value that is found within any list with the key. From your sample, `a` gets `{b,c,e,f}` (We'll call them friends, and this is what the `GetFriends` function does)

The `AreFriendsWithEachother` function indicates whether or not all passed values are friends with all other values.

The results of the friends list are then fed to the `MakeTeam` function which makes teams of a given `size` by enumerating every friend that a key has and trying every `size` length permutation of these. For instance, in the original example `a` has friend permutations of `{{a,b,c},{a,b,e},{a,b,f},{a,c,b},{a,c,e},{a,c,f},{a,e,b},{a,e,c},{a,e,f},{a,f,b},{a,f,c},{a,f,e}}`. Of these we make sure that all three values are friends by checking the friends list we created earlier. If all values within a permutation are friends then we add it to our results cache. The results would then be culled for all duplicate sets. This is handled in C# by using `HashSet` which only adds items that aren't already on the list.

The `MakeTeam` function is terrible looking because it contains a runtime variable number of loops (normally visualized by `foreach`). I am rolling up and down through enumerators and emulating the `foreach` loops myself.

I've included versions for `MakeTeamOf3` and `MakeTeamOf4` which show static loop structures,  which are very easily adapted when you know your `k` value ahead of time.

The same code is provided here

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace kfromkm1 // k elements from k minus 1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static readonly string[][] pairs =
        {
            new string[] { "a", "b" },
            new string[] { "a", "c" },
            new string[] { "b", "c" },
            new string[] { "a", "e" },
            new string[] { "b", "e" },
            new string[] { "a", "f" }
        };

        static readonly string[][] pairsExpectedResult =
        {
            new string[] { "a", "b", "c" },
            new string[] { "a", "b", "e" }
        };

        static readonly string[][] triplets =
        {
            new string[] { "a", "b", "c" },
            new string[] { "a", "b", "d" },
            new string[] { "a", "c", "d" },
            new string[] { "b", "c", "d" },
            new string[] { "b", "c", "e" }
        };

        static readonly string[][] tripletsExpectedResults =
        {
            new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }
        };

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> friendsList = GetFriends(pairs);
            Dump(nameof(pairs), pairs);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Dump(nameof(pairsExpectedResult), pairsExpectedResult);
            Console.WriteLine();
            HashSet<HashSet<string>> teams = MakeTeams(friendsList, 3);
            Dump(nameof(teams), teams);

            Console.WriteLine();

            friendsList = GetFriends(triplets);
            Dump(nameof(triplets), triplets);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Dump(nameof(tripletsExpectedResults), tripletsExpectedResults);
            Console.WriteLine();
            teams = MakeTeams(friendsList, 4);
            Dump(nameof(teams), teams);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // helper function to display results
        static void Dump<T>(string name, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} =");
            int line = 0;
            bool notfirst;
            foreach (IEnumerable<T> layer in values)
            {
                Console.Write($"{line}: {{");
                notfirst = false;
                foreach (T value in layer)
                {
                    if (notfirst)
                        Console.Write($", {value}");
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(value);
                        notfirst = true;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("}");
                line++;
            }
        }

        // items are friends if they show up in a set (pair in the example) together
        // list can be a list of lists, array of arrays, list of arrays, etc
        // {a, b} means a and b are friends
        // {a, b, c} means a is friends with b and c, b is friends with a and c, c is friends with a and b
        static Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> GetFriends<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> list) where T : IEquatable<T>
        {
            Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> result = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();
            foreach (IEnumerable<T> set in list) // one set at a time
            {
                foreach (T current in set) // enumerate the set from front to back
                {
                    foreach (T other in set) // enumerate the set with a second pointer to compare every item
                    {
                        if (!current.Equals(other)) // ignore self
                        {
                            if (!result.ContainsKey(current)) // initialize this item's result hashset
                                result[current] = new HashSet<T>();
                            result[current].Add(other); // add friend (hashset will ignore duplicates)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        // indicates whether or not all items are friends
        static bool AreFriendsWithEachother<T>(Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> friendsList, IEnumerable<T> values)
        {
            if (friendsList == null) // no list = no results
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(friendsList));
            foreach (T first in values)
            {
                if (!friendsList.ContainsKey(first)) // not on list, has no friends
                    return false;
                foreach (T other in values)
                {
                    if (!friendsList[first].Contains(other) && !first.Equals(other)) // false if even one doesn't match, don't count self as non-friend for computational ease
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true; // all matched so true
        }

        // size represents how many items should be in each team
        static HashSet<HashSet<T>> MakeTeams<T>(Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> friendsList, int size) where T : IEquatable<T>
        {
            if (friendsList == null) // no list = no results
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(friendsList));
            if (size < 2)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size), size, "Size should be greater than 2");
            HashSet<HashSet<T>> result = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>(HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer());
            T[] values = new T[size];
            IEnumerator<T>[] enumerators = new IEnumerator<T>[size - 1]; // gotta cache our own enumerators with a variable number of "foreach" layers
            int layer;
            bool moveNext;

            foreach (T key in friendsList.Keys) // this is a mess because it's a runtime variable number of copies of enumerators running over the same list
            {
                values[0] = key;
                for (int index = 0; index < size - 1; index++)
                    enumerators[index] = friendsList[key].GetEnumerator();
                moveNext = true;
                layer = 0;
                while (moveNext)
                {
                    while (layer < size - 1 && moveNext)
                    {
                        if (enumerators[layer].MoveNext())
                            layer++;
                        else
                        {
                            if (layer == 0)
                                moveNext = false;
                            else
                            {
                                enumerators[layer].Reset();
                                layer--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (int index = 1; index < size; index++)
                        values[index] = enumerators[index - 1].Current;
                    if (values.Distinct().Count() == size && AreFriendsWithEachother(friendsList, values))
                        result.Add(new HashSet<T>(values));
                    layer--;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // provided as an example
        static HashSet<HashSet<T>> MakeTeamsOf3<T>(Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> friendsList) where T : IEquatable<T>
        {
            if (friendsList == null) // no list = no results
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(friendsList));
            HashSet<HashSet<T>> result = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>(HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer());
            T[] values;

            foreach (T key in friendsList.Keys) // start with every key
            {
                foreach (T first in friendsList[key])
                {
                    foreach (T second in friendsList[key])
                    {
                        values = new T[] { key, first, second };
                        if (values.Distinct().Count() == 3 && AreFriendsWithEachother(friendsList, values)) // there's no duplicates and they are friends
                            result.Add(new HashSet<T>(values));
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // provided as an example
        static HashSet<HashSet<T>> MakeTeamsOf4<T>(Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> friendsList) where T : IEquatable<T>
        {
            if (friendsList == null) // no list = no results
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(friendsList));
            HashSet<HashSet<T>> result = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>(HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer());
            T[] values;

            foreach (T key in friendsList.Keys) // start with every key
            {
                foreach (T first in friendsList[key])
                {
                    foreach (T second in friendsList[key])
                    {
                        foreach (T third in friendsList[key])
                        {
                            values = new T[] { key, first, second, third };
                            if (values.Distinct().Count() == 4 && AreFriendsWithEachother(friendsList, values)) // there's no duplicates and they are friends
                                result.Add(new HashSet<T>(values));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you appreciate it. I do not use LinkedIn but if you find my answer helped you, you can just mark the post.

Comment: Up at the top of this answer will be some up and down arrows. Up votes the post positively and you should also be able to accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Function to generate SetOfkNbrdElementCombinations 
//to generate outputs with k values greater than two (pairwise)

```
  Take SetOfkNbrdElementCombinations as an input 
  //Example - {{a,b},{b,c},...} : here k is 2 (though variable name will retain the letter k); elements are a,b,c,..; sets {a,b}, {b,c} are 2-numbered combinations of elements

  Take nextSize as an input 
  //nextSize should be bigger than the k in the input SetOfkNbrdElementCombinations by 1. 
  //For example above where k is 2, nextSize would be 3

  //Logic: 
  Comb(SetOfkNbrdElementCombinations={S1,S2,...Sn},nextSize) = {S1,Comb({SetOfkNbrdElementCombinations-a1},nextSize-l)}

  //The recursive algorithm specified in the line above generates sets containing unique nextSize numbered combinations of the combinations in SetOfkNbrdElementCombinations
  //Code that implements the algorithm is available at Rosetta code
  //In our example it would generate {{{a,b},{b,c},{b,e}},{{a,b},{b,c},{a,c}},...} (triplets of pairs)


  //My logic to generate nextSize numbered combinations of elements is below
  // Example of my output, based on the example input above, would be {{a,b,c},{a,c,e},...}

  Intitialize oputSetOfkNbrdElementCombinations to empty

  For each nextSize sized combination of combinations generated above 
      Join the contained combinations in a union set
      If the nbr of elements in the union is nextSize, add the union set to oputSetOfkNbrdElementCombinations

  Output oputSetOfkNbrdElementCombinations
```

Here is the Java implementation of the algorithm.  You can copy, paste and run on https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/

```
/* This program takes k sized element combinations and generates the k+1 sized element combinations
that are possible.  

For example if the program is given {a,b,c}, {a,b,d}, {a,c,d}, {b,c,d}, {b,c,e} 
which are 3 sized combinations, it will identify {a,b,c,d}  the  
4 sized combination that has all the 3 sized combinations of its elements covered
in what were provided to the program

The program can scale to higher values of k.  
The program uses only the hashset data structure
*/

//AUTHOR: Suri Chitti

import java.util.*;
public class uppOrdCombsFromCombs {


 //sample CSV strings...let us pretend they came from a file
 //This is a sample of input to the program
 static String[] csvStrings = new String[] {
                "a,b,c",
                "a,b,d",
                "a,c,d",
                "b,c,d",
                "b,c,e"
        };

/*  //Another sample CSV strings...let us pretend they came from a file
 //This is another sample of input to the program
 static String[] csvStrings = new String[] {
                "a,b",
                "b,c",
                "a,c",
                "c,e",
                "a,e"
        };      
      */  /////USE ONLY ONE SAMPLE

  //Before we can generate a k+1 sized combination of elements from a bunch
  //of k sized combinations we need to obtain groups containing k+1 number of
  // k sized combinations
  //The method below, called SetOfNxtSizeNbrdkElementCombinationsets will do it for us
  //It takes a bunch of k sized combinations called the parameter hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsetsPrm
  //which is a hashset.
  //It also takes k+1 as input called the parameter nextSize which is an integer
  //Outputs k+1 sized groups of k sized element combinations as a variable called hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets
  //which is hashset

  static HashSet SetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets(HashSet hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsetsPrm, Integer nextSize){

      HashSet hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets = new HashSet<>();//is it better to have nested <HashSet> tokens in this declaration?
      HashSet hsRecursor = new HashSet<>(hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsetsPrm);

      Iterator <HashSet> loopIterator1 = hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsetsPrm.iterator();
      while (loopIterator1.hasNext()) {

          HashSet hsName = loopIterator1.next(); 

          if(nextSize == 1){
            hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets.add(hsName);

          }

          else {

            HashSet hsConc1 = new HashSet<>();
            hsRecursor.remove(hsName);

            hsConc1 = SetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets(hsRecursor,nextSize-1);

            Iterator <HashSet> loopIterator2 = hsConc1.iterator();

            while (loopIterator2.hasNext()) {

                HashSet hsConc2 = new HashSet<>();
                HashSet hsConc3 = new HashSet<>();

                hsConc2 = loopIterator2.next(); 

                Iterator <HashSet> loopIterator3 = hsConc2.iterator();

                Object obj = loopIterator3.next();

                if (String.class.isInstance(obj)) {
                    hsConc3.add(hsName);
                    hsConc3.add(hsConc2);

                }
                else {
                    loopIterator3 = hsConc2.iterator();
                    hsConc3.add(hsName);
                    while (loopIterator3.hasNext()) {
                    hsConc3.add(loopIterator3.next());
                    }
                } 
                 hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets.add(hsConc3);
            }
           }

        }
      return hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets;
  }

  //The method below takes the k+1 sized groupings of k sized element combinations
  //generated by the method above and  generates all possible K+1 sized combinations of 
  //elements contained in them
  //Name of the method is SetOfkNbrdCombinationsets 
  //It takes the k+1 sized groupings in a parameter called hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsetsPrm which is a HashSet
  //It takes the value k+1 as a parameter called nextSize which is an Integer
  //It returns k+1 sized combinations as a variable called hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets which is a HashSet
  //This is the intended output of the whole program

  static HashSet SetOfkNbrdCombinationsets(HashSet hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsetsPrm, Integer nextSize){
      HashSet hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets = new HashSet<>();
      HashSet hsMember = new HashSet<>();

      Iterator <HashSet> loopIteratorOverParam = hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsetsPrm.iterator();
      while (loopIteratorOverParam.hasNext()) {
      hsMember = loopIteratorOverParam.next();


      HashSet hsInnerUnion = new HashSet<>();
      Iterator <HashSet> loopIteratorOverMember = hsMember.iterator();
       while (loopIteratorOverMember.hasNext()) {
           HashSet hsInnerMemb = new HashSet<>(loopIteratorOverMember.next());
           hsInnerUnion.addAll(hsInnerMemb);
        }



       if (hsInnerUnion.size()==nextSize) {
           HashSet hsTemp = new HashSet<>(hsInnerUnion);
           hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets.add(hsTemp);

       }
       hsInnerUnion.clear();
       }
       return hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets;
      }


  public static void main(String args[]) {

   HashSet hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets = new HashSet<>();//should this have nested <HashSet> tokens?
   HashSet hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets = new HashSet<>();//should this have nested <HashSet> tokens?

   Integer innerSize=0,nextSize  = 0;


   System.out.println("Ahoy");

   //pretend we are looping through lines in a file here
   for(String line : csvStrings)
        {
            String[] linePieces = line.split(",");
            List<String> csvPieces = new ArrayList<String>(linePieces.length);
            for(String piece : linePieces)
            {   
                //System.out.println(piece); will print each piece in separate lines
                csvPieces.add(piece);
            }
            innerSize = csvPieces.size();
            Set<String> hsInner =  new HashSet<String>(csvPieces);
            hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets.add(hsInner);

        }

   nextSize = innerSize+1; //programmatically obtain nextSize



   hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets = SetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets(hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets,nextSize);
   hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets = SetOfkNbrdCombinationsets(hsSetOfNxtSizeNbrdCombinationsets, nextSize);

   System.out.println("The " + nextSize  + " sized combinations from elements present in the input combinations are: " + hsSetOfkNbrdCombinationsets);


} //end of main
} //end of class
```